# How to get all possible solutions using backtracking algorithm?

Tags: c#, solution, sudoku, backtracking

I'm using the backtracking algorithm described [in this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-gpaIGRCQI).

Now, I should be able to get ALL possible solutions. Am I able to do this with the backtracking algoritme and how? If not possible, which other (simple) algorithm should I use?

Comment: Have you tried to use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is not a great fit for this site since it does not appear to be about actual code.

But I'll take a shot at it anyways.

Of course you can get all possible solutions with a backtracking algorithm. Remember how a backtracking algorithm works:

```
while(there are still guesses available)
    make a guess
    solve the puzzle with the guess
    if there was a solution then record the solution and quit the loop.
    cross the guess off the list of possible guesses
if you recorded a solution then the puzzle is solvable.
```

If you want all solutions then just modify the algorithm to:

```
while(there are still guesses available)
    make a guess
    solve the puzzle with the guess
    if there was a solution then record the solution. Don't quit.
    cross the guess off the list of possible guesses
if you recorded any solution then the puzzle is solvable.
```

Incidentally, I wrote a series of blog articles on solving sudoku in C# using a graph-colouring backtracking algorithm; it might be of interest to you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/graph-colouring-with-simple-backtracking-part-one

In this code you'll see the line:

```
return solutions.FirstOrDefault();
```

"solutions" contains a query that enumerates all solutions. I only want the first such solution, so that's what I ask it for. If you want every solution, just rewrite the program so that it does not call `FirstOrDefault`. See the comments below for some notes.

Comment: If memory serves that blog article is written to provide one valid solution rather than all.  It's possible to alter it to return all solutions, but then that's what this question is asking... It's a great blog series though.

Comment: @Servy: Correct, but it is a simple modification to the code. Recall that I produce a query that represents all solutions and then call `return solutions.FirstOrDefault();`  -- if you want every solution, just take the `FirstOrDefault` off of there and return `solutions` instead.

Comment: I remember when I first read the series I made the modification to return all as an exercise, and it's not *quite* that simple, mostly since you need to no longer have `null` values and instead have empty collections, and then the other aspects of the algorithm that relied on null checks need to be changed, and you don't want to be iterating sequence multiple times, so all in all it wasn't *super* hard, but it wasn't just as simple as removing `FirstOrDefault` either.

Comment: I don't have the code anymore, but I'll see if I can re-write it again.  I remember wondering at the time why you didn't write it from the start to return all, since you can always call `FirstOrDefault` at the very end to get the first, but since you built it into the algorithm it made it much harder to go the other way.

Comment: Okay, so I just re-wrote it, and here are the changes that need to be made to `Solve`: first base case needs to be changed to: `return new[] { this.possibilities.SelectMany(x => x) };` second base case needs to be changed to: `return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<int>>();` and third base case needs to be changed to: `return solutions.SelectMany(x => x);`.  The signature of `Solve` also needs to be changed to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`.  Now, that's not a huge, huge change, but I don't know if I'd expect just anyone to be able to make it without a noticeable time investment.

Comment: It seems the link to MS doesn't work. :(